# Python api request

Tags: python

I am very new to fetching data using an API and am trying to get the names of the pro teams from http://developer.cbssports.com/documentation/api/files/pro-teams#/pro_teams

This is what I tried which doesn't work. I just want nickname and name for NBA teams

EDIT: I updated the URL. Now I just need to figure out how to extract the nickname and name for the teams

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError

request = Request('http://api.cbssports.com/fantasy/pro-teams?version=3.0&SPORT=basketball')

try:
    response = urlopen(request)
    teams = response.read()
    print teams
except URLError, e:
    print 'error:', e
```

Comment: currently i get a 500 server error.

Comment: I copy that URL into the browser and it gives me an internal server error. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I got it from here http://developer.cbssports.com/documentation/api/files/pro-teams#/pro_teams/pro_team

Comment: Their documentation seems to be incomplete.  They say "for a sport" but don't tell you how to specify their sport.  Their football and baseball examples use the same exact URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an access token to use the api. See http://developer.cbssports.com/documentation/tutorial.